# My website button works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, web, firefox, button

im trying to figure out why the search button (top right) is working for Chrome but not for Firefox. Take a look: https://lectulandia.us

```html
<li class="formWrapper">
<form class="bookSearch" action="/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
</li>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Also not working any browser

Comment: can you use toggle jquery

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try to solve this issue 
and what problem did you encounter exactly?

Comment: I haven't tried anything since my programming skills are too basic. When you click on the top right magnifying glass, a box should pop up on the left to search for content. If you press the magnifying glass and type something, if you press enter it search it. It is like the effect isnt working. There is also a website with my theme using the same search bar that is working: lectulandia.cc